# Spacing between the stars of a rating bar?

Tags: android

ho can I set a spacing beween the stars? Thats my ratingbar:

```
ratingBar = (RatingBar) inflater.inflate(R.layout.ratingbar, null);
ratingBar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RatingBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/myStyle" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_height="19dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5">
</RatingBar>
```

The style:

```
 <style name="myStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/android_r2_ratingstar_yellow</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/android_r2_ratingstar_grey</item>
 </style>
```

Thanks, cheers

Comment: You might try to add a padding to the picture itself, by adding some transparent border on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the padding to the png itself. While there is something known as an Inset Drawable (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Inset) that you could wrap your drawable into, the code for 'tileify'-ing (as referred to in the android source code) doesn't handle the case of drawable being an inset drawable, and hence doesn't tile the image.

Here's the tilefy method (in ProgressBar.java, which is the ancestor to RatingBar.java: https://gist.github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread/core/java/android/widget/ProgressBar.java)

```
private Drawable tileify(Drawable drawable, boolean clip) {

    if (drawable instanceof LayerDrawable) {
        LayerDrawable background = (LayerDrawable) drawable;
        final int N = background.getNumberOfLayers();
        Drawable[] outDrawables = new Drawable[N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int id = background.getId(i);
            outDrawables[i] = tileify(background.getDrawable(i),
                    (id == R.id.progress || id == R.id.secondaryProgress));
        }

        LayerDrawable newBg = new LayerDrawable(outDrawables);

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            newBg.setId(i, background.getId(i));
        }

        return newBg;

    } else if (drawable instanceof StateListDrawable) {
        StateListDrawable in = (StateListDrawable) drawable;
        StateListDrawable out = new StateListDrawable();
        int numStates = in.getStateCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < numStates; i++) {
            out.addState(in.getStateSet(i), tileify(in.getStateDrawable(i), clip));
        }
        return out;

    } else if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        final Bitmap tileBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        if (mSampleTile == null) {
            mSampleTile = tileBitmap;
        }

        final ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(getDrawableShape());

        final BitmapShader bitmapShader = new BitmapShader(tileBitmap,
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setShader(bitmapShader);

        return (clip) ? new ClipDrawable(shapeDrawable, Gravity.LEFT,
                ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL) : shapeDrawable;
    }

    return drawable;
}
```

Comment: Your post is a bit confusing - is it possible without modifying the png or not? Does tileify method solve it? How to add padding with it? If not, why do you post it?

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to modify the padding between images, better save time and simply add some space with any available image editor.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this library.

https://github.com/CaiJingLong/Android-CustomRatingBar

I can easily add padding like

app:padding="20dp"

[Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQykv.png)

How to use:

```html
<com.kikt.view.CustomRatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:currentStar="3.5"
            app:fullStar="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:maxStar="5"
            app:minStar="0.5"
            app:padding="3dp"
            app:starHeight="30dp"
            app:starWidth="30dp"/>
```