# Spacing between stars in Custom Rating Bar

Tags: android

[Spacing between the stars of a rating bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213784/spacing-between-the-stars-of-a-rating-bar)

I have similar problem but I didn't find solution to make it without changes of images.
Maybe someome faced with such problem and solved it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the screenshot of your custom rating bar.

Comment: It's like default android rating bar only smaller - default rating bar have not spacing between stars.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom style that uses your own images with different spacing between them.

Use it in a layout like this:

```
<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/RatingBarLarge"/>
```

Define the style like this:

```
<style name="RatingBarLarge">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ic_rating_star_large</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">29dp</item>
</style>
```

Set the minHeight to whatever the height of your drawable is.
Then, define ic_rating_star_large as a layer list like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rate_star_large_off" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rate_star_large_off" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rate_star_large_on" />
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this same kind of code for your  rating bar?

//  ?android:attr/ratingBarStyle- normal star

// ?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall - small star

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/toast_frame">
    <RatingBar android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"
        android:id="@+id/ratingbar_default" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"

         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Default android rating bar has not spacing between stars.But I need to do it. For example 5px between each star in rating bar.