# Space Between stars of ratingBar

Tags: android, rating

I need insert a space between the stars of my ratingBar, example the ratingbar is well:

[image]

but I need it thus:

[image]

how i can do this?

Comment: See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213784/spacing-between-the-stars-of-a-rating-bar).

Comment: I have added a feature request, please vote for it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230511

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if it will be useful anymore, but I made a custom library which allows you to change space beetwen stars programatically and in XML (among other stuff): [SimpleRatingBar](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar).

It features:

- Fully working `android:layout_width`: it can be set to `wrap_content`, `match_parent` or abritary dp.
- Arbitrary number of stars.
- Arbitrary step size.
- Size of stars can be controlled exactly or by setting a maximum size.
- Customizable colors in normal state (border, fill and background of stars and rating bar).
- Customizable colors in pressed state (border, fill and background of stars and rating bar).
- Customizable size separation between stars.
- Customizable border width of stars.
- Customizable stars corner radius.
- Allows to set OnRatingBarChangeListener
- Stars fill can be set to start from left to right or from right to left (RTL language support).
- AnimationBuilder integrated in the view to set rating programatically with animation.

[Here is a preview of it](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar/raw/master/images/sample.gif).

In your case, you would just have to do:

```
ratingbar.setStarsSeparation(20, Dimension.DP);
```

or, for example, in pixels:

```
ratingbar.setStarsSeparation(100, Dimension.PX);
```

You can find it either in `jcenter` or in `Maven Central`. So in your `build.gradle` file just add to your dependencies:

`compile 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.+'`

Comment: It doesn't support custom drawable for stars. Or does it?

Comment: Hi @FoY, it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

You have a next property.

```
android:progressDrawable = "@drawable/rating_stars"
android:indeterminateDrawable = "@drawable/rating_stars"
```

@drawable/rating_stars :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star" />
</layer-list>
```

star_empty and star are the images which are in your drawable directory.
So, you can change star and star_empty in a graphic editor and add a spassing if you need.

Comment: Yes I agree, but. Now consider the following, you will make 4 types of ratingbars on a large project, each ratingbar with 3 different types of drawable are about 12 images that put, say, 2px of space, now think it necessary to increase 1px space, I prefer to change setPadding(2) to setPadding(3) instead of reissue than 10 images

Comment: By adding inset in left and/or right of the drawable, we get unwanted padding on left and/or right border of the View.

Comment: very late but I'll something else: doing so, will break if stepSize is <1 as the renderer will consider the whole image event the margin

Answer (score 1):

Just use the custom icon for it and do use the style , i mean Photoshop it as you want it to look and replace with the system rating style icon.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to grab a copy of the systems star png file and manually add the padding that you want to it with a photoshop / gimp / some other editor.

Comment: As per the links I posted above, I believe you can customize the `Drawable` used for the stars using the size attributes to fake padding (by setting up a `style` tag for the `RatingBar`).

Comment: this way had been ugly, don't have a way in configurations of ratingbar class

Comment: @Soxxeh Hmm, Im not finding an example of that in either link that you posted. The first one seems more promising, but the first sentence says: "You have to add the padding to the png itself" and goes on to show a method from the ProgressBar class. I don't see anywhere a style that affected the padding. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Tim Argh, my bad, I misread the second link I posted. (It was changing the actual image size, not the size+padding...) I'll comment on that above.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to Tim 
i applied same logic and it worked.
Here in my project i am using my own star images for the star ratin
I made star images having extra space (padding) on the right side that resulted in space between the stars

Comment: Yes I agree, but. Now consider the following, you will make 4 types of ratingbars on a large project, each ratingbar with 2 or 3 different types of drawable are about 10 images that put, say, 2px of space, now think it necessary to increase 1px space, I prefer to change setPadding(2) to setPadding(3) instead of reissue than 10 images.

Comment: have you got a solution in your way. Please share what did you tried the best

Comment: unfortunately found nothing elegant to solve this, I put spacing in own image :( , I did not like the issue resolved in the hope of one day finding a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Custom SVG and Set Your Separation value**

By using this class, you can fix Android custom SVG RatingBar and set Drawable End by replacing value(I marked this value as There_You_Can_Set_Your_Value) inside the class.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapShader
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Shader
import android.graphics.drawable.*
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.RoundRectShape
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.Gravity
import androidx.appcompat.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRatingBar

class RatingBarSvg @JvmOverloads
constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.ratingBarStyle,
) : AppCompatRatingBar(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var mSampleTile: Bitmap? = null

    private val drawableShape: Shape
        get() {
            val roundedCorners = floatArrayOf(5f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f, 5f)
            return RoundRectShape(roundedCorners, null, null)
        }

    init {
        val drawable = tileify(progressDrawable, false) as LayerDrawable
        //drawable.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background).setColorFilter(backgroundTintColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        //drawable.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress).setColorFilter(progressTintColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        progressDrawable = drawable
    }

    /**
     * Converts a drawable to a tiled version of itself. It will recursively
     * traverse layer and state list drawables.
     */
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private fun tileify(drawable: Drawable, clip: Boolean): Drawable {
        if (drawable is DrawableWrapper) {
            var inner: Drawable? = drawable.wrappedDrawable
            if (inner != null) {
                inner = tileify(inner, clip)
                drawable.wrappedDrawable = inner
            }
        } else if (drawable is LayerDrawable) {
            val numberOfLayers = drawable.numberOfLayers
            val outDrawables = arrayOfNulls<Drawable>(numberOfLayers)

            for (i in 0 until numberOfLayers) {
                val id = drawable.getId(i)
                outDrawables[i] = tileify(
                    drawable.getDrawable(i),
                    id == android.R.id.progress || id == android.R.id.secondaryProgress
                )
            }

            val newBg = LayerDrawable(outDrawables)

            for (i in 0 until numberOfLayers) {
                newBg.setId(i, drawable.getId(i))
            }

            return newBg

        } else if (drawable is BitmapDrawable) {
            val tileBitmap = drawable.bitmap
            if (mSampleTile == null) {
                mSampleTile = tileBitmap
            }

            val shapeDrawable = ShapeDrawable(drawableShape)
            val bitmapShader = BitmapShader(
                tileBitmap,
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
            )
            shapeDrawable.paint.shader = bitmapShader
            shapeDrawable.paint.colorFilter = drawable.paint.colorFilter
            return if (clip)
                ClipDrawable(
                    shapeDrawable, Gravity.START,
                    ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL
                )
            else
                shapeDrawable
        } else {
            return tileify(getBitmapDrawableFromVectorDrawable(drawable), clip)
        }

        return drawable
    }

    private fun getBitmapDrawableFromVectorDrawable(drawable: Drawable): BitmapDrawable {
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            drawable.intrinsicWidth + (**There_You_Can_Set_Your_Value**).toInt(), //dp between svg images  //* resources.displayMetrics.density
            drawable.intrinsicHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.intrinsicWidth, drawable.intrinsicHeight)
        drawable.draw(canvas)
        return BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap)
    }

    @Synchronized
    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        if (mSampleTile != null) {
            val width = mSampleTile!!.width * numStars
            setMeasuredDimension(
                resolveSizeAndState(width, widthMeasureSpec, 0),
                measuredHeight
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the value you are adding is going to be added to the width of the drawable instead of the padding

Answer (score 0):

For those who follow [prsnlme answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69260799/16348805), Use the `SvgRatingBar` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53589663/16348805) and then edit the `getBitmapDrawableFromVectorDrawable()` function like below to add horizontal padding to the `SvgRatingBar`

```
 private fun getBitmapDrawableFromVectorDrawable(drawable: Drawable): BitmapDrawable {


    val padding : Int = (**Here_You_Can_Set_Your_Value**)


    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        drawable.intrinsicWidth + padding / 2 + padding,
        drawable.intrinsicHeight,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    // canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE); // this line is for better view on the padding
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, padding.toFloat() * 2, 0F, null)
    drawable.setBounds(
        padding / 2,
        0,
        drawable.intrinsicWidth + padding,
        drawable.intrinsicHeight
    )
    drawable.draw(canvas)
    return BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap)
}
```