# Separate stars in a ratingbar

Tags: android, ratingbar

I need to separate the stars in a `RatingBar`, it's possible? Or have I to create my own `RatingBar`?

```
<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="7"
    android:id="@+id/estrellas2"
    android:scaleX="1.2"
    android:scaleY="1.2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>
```

Comment: Are you want to make some space between stars ?

Comment: @SahdevRajput74 Exactly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Space Between stars of ratingBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092461/space-between-stars-of-ratingbar)

Comment: **Check this**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092461/space-between-stars-of-ratingbar **Maybe useful**

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_ratingbar_selector"
```

property to customize rating bar .

and

Create `custom_ratingbar_selector.xml` in drawable and paste this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/unslected_star_icon" />

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/unslected_star_icon" />

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/slected_star_icon" />

</layer-list>
```

Comment: He didn't mean a custom style for rateBar.

Comment: he asked "  have i to create my own RatingBar? "

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,
 android:progressDrawable = "@drawable/rat_star"
 android:indeterminateDrawable = "@drawable/rat_star"

@drawable/rat_star :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/starempty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/starempty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star" />
</layer-list>
```