# How to decrease the star size and add a spacing between stars in the RatingBar Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, ratingbar

I need to use the RatingBar in my android app with kotlin.
I want to decrease the size of star and add a spacing between starsin the RatingBar. 
Here's my code, but I didn't get what I want.

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleX=".5"
        android:scaleY=".5"
        android:transformPivotX="0dp"
        android:transformPivotY="0dp"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/rating_bar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/itemProdImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewNameProduct"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="1"
        android:stepSize="3" />
```

The following code is rating_bar.xml :

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/icn_star_empty"/>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/icn_star" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/icn_star" />
</layer-list>
```

The following picture present the result of my code :
[image]

The other picture present the result what I want :
[image]

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Space Between stars of ratingBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092461/space-between-stars-of-ratingbar)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but, I still not have what I want