# Adding Margin/Padding to a RatingBar

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, drawable

I have an image of a rating bar like this:

[image]

Now, I would like to know how would I add a margin/padding to each item in the rating bar?

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
<style name="starRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@layout/starratingbar_full</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">19dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">19dp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

**starratingbar_full.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:layout_width="30dp">

<item android:id="@+android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/starunselected"
    />
<item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/starunselected" />
<item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/starselected" />
</layer-list>
```

**activity.xml**

```
<RatingBar
style="@style/starRatingBar"
android:numStars="5"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
android:stepSize="1"/>
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spacing between the stars of a rating bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213784/spacing-between-the-stars-of-a-rating-bar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using any photoshop or any editor
simply You could add some empty space to the left and right sides of your PNGs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Drawable for the stars. Make sure your drawable have some left padding according to your requirement.

**Otherwise through code its not working**. Some days back I stuck with the same problem. I gone through by using the left padded image. Hope it will work.