# Change Spacing between stars in a Ratingbar

Tags: android, spacing, ratingbar

Here is the part of the code that I defined my Ratingbar.
I want to know, how can I change the space between the stars?

```
protected Object createControl() {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final RatingBar ratingBar = new android.widget.RatingBar(getContext());
    LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
    ratingBar.setStepSize((float) 1.0);
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {

            LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
            DrawableCompat.setTint(DrawableCompat.wrap(layerDrawable.getDrawable(0)), Color.parseColor("#3C3F41"));
            DrawableCompat.setTint(DrawableCompat.wrap(layerDrawable.getDrawable(1)), Color.parseColor("#F7C065"));
            DrawableCompat.setTint(DrawableCompat.wrap(layerDrawable.getDrawable(2)), Color.parseColor("#F7C065"));
        }
    });
    layout.addView(ratingBar, params);
    return layout;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213784/spacing-between-the-stars-of-a-rating-bar)  , You may Find Something Useful